# Необходимо зациклить выражение до определённого момента

Tags: c#

```
 Double x = Convert.ToDouble(vvod_x.Text);
 Double n = Convert.ToDouble(vvod_n.Text);
 for (int j = 0; j < n; j++);
 Double s = ((2 * j + 5) * Math.Pow(x, 2)) / (2 * Math.Abs(j));
```

Он почему то не видит переменную j

Comment: Потому что у вас тело цикла пустое - состоит из одной точки с запятой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From:

```
 Double x = Convert.ToDouble(vvod_x.Text);
 Double n = Convert.ToDouble(vvod_n.Text);
 for (int j = 0; j < n; j++);
 Double s = ((2 * j + 5) * Math.Pow(x, 2)) / (2 * Math.Abs(j));
```

To:

```
 Double x = Convert.ToDouble(vvod_x.Text);
 Double n = Convert.ToDouble(vvod_n.Text);
 Double s; 
 for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
 {
    s = ((2 * j + 5) * Math.Pow(x, 2)) / (2 * Math.Abs(j)); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо стереть точку с запятой после оператора for, иначе у вас получается цикл без тела:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++);
```

нужно переделать в

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
```

Comment: Ввел S как переменную в начале и формулу указал ниже, помогло, также убрал точку с запятой.